# intersection of a line and a plane

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

My kid was given this problem:

> Line $\ell_1$ is given by $(1,4,2)+t(2,-1,-2)$. Line $\ell_2$ passes through the point $A=(6,0,-3)$, is parallel to the plane $\pi$ given by $3x-4y+z-10=0$, and intersects $\ell_1$ at $B$. (1) Find, in terms of $t$, the directional vector of $\ell_2$. (2) Find $B$.

So I decided to find $B$ first. I found the plane parallel to $\pi$ through $A$ to be $3x-4y+z-15=0$, and put $(1-2t,4-t,2-2t)$ in for $(x,y,z)$ in that equation to find $B$. I wound up with $(7.5,0.75,-1.5)$, which seems exceedingly unlikely for a normal high-school math-book problem (and subsequent analysis shows, in fact, an inconsistency). What did I do wrong? What should I have done instead?

Comment: All of your ideas were good, but you made some arithmetic mistakes. I've posted an explanation below. If you have any questions, let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You made at least one arithmetic mistake. Everything else about your solution was fine.

First, you are correct that $A$ and $B$ will be contained in the plane given by the equation $3x-4y+z=15$. Let's call this plane $\pi_2$.

Next, you tried to find $B$ by using the fact that $B$ is the unique point in $\ell_1\cap\pi_2$. Plugging $(1+2t,4-t,2-2t)$ into $3x-4y+z=15$, you get that $t=\frac{13}{4}=3.25$. Hence $B=(7.5,0.75,-4.5)$.

Now $\ell_2$ is the set of points of the form $A+t(B-A)=(6,0,-3)+t\cdot(1.5,0.75,-1.5)$. So the directional vector is $(1.5,0.75,-1.5)$.

You can check that every point of the form $A+t(B-A)$ is on $\pi_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The normal vector of the given plane $3x-4y+z-10=0$ is $(3, -4,1)$. Then, the equation of the plane parallel to it and passing the point $A(6,0,-3)$ is

$$(x-6, y, z+3)\cdot (3, -4,1)=0\implies 3x-4y+z-15=0$$

Substitute the given line $(x,y,z)=(1+2t, 4-t, 2-2t)$ into above plane to get $t$ for point B,

$$3(1+2t)-4(4-t)+(2-2t)-15=0\implies t=\frac{13}4$$

Plug $t$ back into the given line $(1+2t, 4-t, 2-2t) $ to obtain the point B$(\frac{15}2,\frac34,-\frac92)$.

Comment: I think you made an arithmetic mistake. If $t=\frac{13}{4}$, then $B=(\frac{15}{2},\frac{3}{4},-\frac{9}{2})$.

Comment: There is no need to repeat the solution for a typo. Thanks for spotting it

Comment: I was working on my solution, and I hadn't noticed that you had posted yours until I had posted mine.